# Trying to pull GA Data for analysis. Full data is not coming. Getting an error need help is resolving-look second code piece

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-api, google-reporting-api

I need itemQuantity, itemRevenue, productName, transactionID. But when I am pulling all 4 together. Unable to get full data. So my approach is pulling transactionID first that is 37 000 something values saved that to data_frame_eight then running a for loop over those transactionIDs and then for that particular id pulling itemRevenue, productName and itemQuantity. Rbinding it to a data frame. In the end I need a final data frame with  transactionID, itemRevenue, productName, itemQuantity together. This data frame will have multiple occurences of the transactionID as it going to be expanded by product name. Don't bother about the first for loop it is working perfectly fine. Logic - vise this approach is perfectly fine. help is needed in resolving the error

```
date_inputs <- read_excel("C:/Users/.../input_file.xlsx")
fetched_data_eight <-  data.frame() 
for (i in 1:nrow(date_inputs)) {
  if(is.na(date_inputs$Status[i])){
    # Get the start and end dates from the date_inputs data frame
    view_id <- date_inputs$View_ID[i]
    start_date <- as.Date(date_inputs$Start_Date[i])
    end_date <- as.Date(date_inputs$End_Date[i])
    
    # Query Google Analytics API for the specified date range and store the results
    datanp <- google_analytics(view_id,
                             date_range = c(start_date, end_date),
                             metrics = c("ga:transactionRevenue"),
                             dimensions = c("ga:transactionId", "ga:date"),
                             anti_sample = TRUE, 
    )
    
    str(datanp)
    
    # Append the fetched data to the existing data frame
    fetched_data_eight <- bind_rows(fetched_data_eight, datanp)
    
    # Pause for a few seconds to avoid API rate limits
    Sys.sleep(3)
    
    
    date_inputs$Status[i] <- "Done"
    writexl::write_xlsx(date_inputs, "input_file.xlsx")
  }}
```

Help needed here in the second error

```
for (t in 1:length(fetched_data_eight$transactionId)  ){
    id <- fetched_data_eight$transactionId[t]
    dimensions_filter <- list(dimension_name = "ga:transactionId", 
                              operator = "EXACT", 
                              expressions = id)
    
    my_filter <- filter_clause_ga4(list(dimensions_filter))
    
    datanpq <- google_analytics(view_id,
                               date_range = c("2018-10-01", "2023-05-24"),
                               metrics = c("ga:itemQuantity"),
                               dimensions = c("ga:productName"),
                               dim_filters = my_filter,
                               anti_sample = TRUE
    )
}
```

Error in filter_clause_ga4(list(dimensions_filter)) :
types[1] %in% c("dim_fil_ga4", "met_fil_ga4") is not TRUE